# Ошибка при попытке максимизации функции модулем scipy при вводе через Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Код:

```
import numpy
import math
from scipy.optimize import fmin_slsqp

def f(x, sign=-1):   
    return eval(str(sign) + '* (' + input() + ')')

res = fmin_slsqp(f, [5, 5], iter = 10000)
print(res)
```

При исполнении воозникает ошибка `failed in converting 8th argument g of _slsqp.slsqp to C/Fortran array`
Пример функции: `20*x[0]**0.3*x[1]**0.4 - 2*x[0] - 3*x[1]`
При этом если указать эту же функцию в коде, а не через ввод и `eval`, то все работает

Comment: В целом странно выглядит функция f, вы собираетесь 10000 тысяч раз вводит что то при помощи input?

Comment: нет, тут iter означает что то вроде максимального количества проходов по оптимизации, а не ввода) fmin_slsqp это стандартная функция модуля scipy, проводящая минимизацию переданной ей функции

Comment: У меня ошибки такой нет, просто просит ввести функцию каждый раз.
http://rghost.ru/8sxZzbPS8.view

Comment: Что есть логично. Так как для оптимизации он вызывает функцию столько раз пока не оптимизирует ее. И соответственно input будет вызываться столько же раз.

Answer (score 1):

Может вы хотели что то такое?

```
import numpy
import math
from scipy.optimize import fmin_slsqp

while True:
    s = input("Please input equation:")
    if s == 'stop':
        break

    f = lambda x, sign=-1: eval(str(sign) + '* (' + s + ')')

    res = fmin_slsqp(f, [5, 5], iter = 10000)
    print(res)
```

На вашем уравнении будет так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам! В таком виде заработало. Судя по всему ошибка не возникает, если использовать отдельную переменную для ввода функции сперва, а потом уже ее отдавать на оптимизацию